# webview и лимитное соединение

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Есть на форме некий webview, навигация осуществляется к форматированной HTML string, в ней, соответственно, есть картинки, видео и прочее.

Необходимо заставить этот webview не выкачивать с интернета эти картинки, а отображать строку, как будто интернета вообще нету (аля режим лимитного подключения).

Как такое сделать? Никаких похожих свойств элемента webview я не нашел, пока на ум приходит только парсинг строки и удаление тегов с внешним контентом, но может быть, есть решение и не надо выдумывать велосипед.

Comment: скажем так, WebView весьма геморный элемент, который (по крайней мере в вп80, вп81) известен грустными мемори ликами, вылетами на различных скриптах, отдельным кешем. Не самый приятный элемент. Это так, просто мысли в слух :)

а по поводу вашей проблемы - такой свойства у него увы нет. ваш вариант вполне неплох и имеет право на реализацию)

Comment: @AndriiKrupka а есть ли возможность прервать загрузку страницы webview?

Comment: я не сталкивался с таким, не знаю